# Is there a way to read private variables like eclipse does?

Tags: java

in the image below I have, eclipse show me that my "root" variables has a nested variable named"localSymbolTable" and it has another nested variable named "data".

[image]
As these variables are private, I cannot access them directly. The method to access them thrown me a NullPointerException for other reasons. I really need to read the value of "data" variable, exactly as eclipse is doing in debug mode. Is there a way to do this coding. If so, how can I do this?

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: If it's private, you shouldn't be accessing it directly. You can use reflection to get the fields, but that defeats the purpose of the private field, and is likely dangerous for various reasons.

Comment: Use reflection, but keep in mind that reflection will decrease the performance of your code.

Comment: Doesn't make more sense to **fix the apparent bugs** in the accessors,  rather than doing extra work to avoid using the accessors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection in Java allows you to this.
Check the example in [here](https://www.journaldev.com/1789/java-reflection-example-tutorial#get-set-private-field)

In your case the code would look something like:

```
Field dataField = root.getLocalSymbolTable().getClass().getDeclaredField("data");
dataField.setAccessible(true);
Object dataFieldValue = dataField.get(root.getLocalSymbolTable());
```

Of course, field are private for a reason, see other comments and so on.

Comment: privateField.get ? or dataField.get?